# What is property or limitation of directed the content into test file using > (operator)

Tags: batch-file

When I am using > to copy (or directed) the path into test file.

for e.g: c:>any_path > abc.txt

but when the path size is exceed more than 73 or 76 characters split in another line into file. But we need whole path in single line. Is it limitation in cmd for > (redirect operator). I am using windows7 and XP, both having same problem.

I have resolved that issue in another way. But I want to know that why split the path after 73 or 76 characters when redirected the contents into test file?

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 1):

No. I think you have a confusion here.

First of all, this command:

```
any_path > abc.txt
```

is invalid (what is the *command* here?). You may show the path via PATH or ECHO commands this way:

```
PATH > abc.txt
ECHO %PATH%> abc.txt
```

or insert any path this way:

```
ECHO any_path> abc.txt
```

These commands (nor any other one, for that case) split the line at any character. You may check this with Notepad editor turning Format-> WordWrap option off...

Comment: @Achini: You are right I am using echo %path%>abc.txt, I am using like that:
After getting the path into a text file. then I have taken abc.txt file as a input in another script, and when reading line by line in abc.txt file, some path is reading in two line. why ?

Comment: @user1511510: It seems hard to answer your question without a proper example. Could you perhaps set up a test case for us to try to see the problem and to be able to find a solution for it? Adding such an example to your original post would be really great.